# how to keep file handle open in c after exiting function

Tags: c, linux, procfile

I am trying to read proc file /proc/stat at periodic interval but I want to avoid having to open and close the proc file each time I want to access it.

I want to open the file in sort of init function, and then keep using it in some other function, then close it later on.

It seems file handles opened by a function gets closed when the function exits
How can I keep it open ?

Please let me know if I should be doing it in some other manner

Sample of what I am trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printer(FILE* fin)
{
  /* I am getting fin as NULL */
  if(!fin)
    return 1;

  char buf[16*1024];
  rewind(fin);
  size_t sz = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fin);
  if (sz) {
    buf[sz]=0;
    printf(buf);
  }

  return 0;
}

int opener(FILE *fin)
{
  fin = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
  if (!fin) {
    perror("fopen");
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

int main() {
  FILE *fin;
  /* 
   * I know it works if I open the file handle in here instead of
   * in another function but I want to avoid this
   */
  if(opener(fin)) 
  {
      printf("ERROR1\n");
      return 0;
  }

  while(1) {
    if(printer(fin))
    {   
      printf("ERROR2\n");
      break;
    }   
    sleep(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The file will stay opened until you call `fclose`, which you don't...

Comment: Why do you have a C++ tag? That said, you pass around pointers that get copied, a change on one copy has no influence on the original. Research "call by reference".

Comment: Just a side-note: You're missing an `<unistd.h>` include for `sleep()`. Omitting it is not portable.

Comment: Do you really want a solution written in C++?

Comment: If you want `fin` to be updated, your functions need to take pointers to a file handle - i.e. take a `FILE**`, not a `FILE*`.

Comment: sorry for the c++ tag

Comment: As @RedAlert said --- *or* you can just make the `opener()` return a `FILE*` (or `NULL` on error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in c are pass by value. So when you pass a file handle to a function, it receives a copy of that handle and will update it locally. If you want those updates to propagate to your caller, you need pass file handle pointers. So your open would look like:

```
int opener(FILE **fin)
{
  *fin = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
  if (!(*fin)) {
    perror("fopen");
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And you would call it like:

```
int main() {
  FILE *fin;
  /* 
   * I know it works if I open the file handle in here instead of
   * in another function but I want to avoid this
   */
  if(opener(&fin)) 
  {
      printf("ERROR1\n");
      return 0;
  }
/...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference to the pointer to fin in order to keep it in main.

```
if(opener(&fin)) {}
```

pass it as double pointer :

```
int opener(FILE **fin) {}
```

and use it with derefencing

```
*fin = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
```

otherwise you initiate it everytime you call your subfonction.

Answer (score 0):

The C language passes arguments by value, so the `fin` that `opener` has is a copy of the `fin` that `main` has. Changing `fin` in `opener` has no effect on main's copy.

One solution is to use a temporary file pointer in `opener` and then return that pointer. To indicate an error, return NULL.

```
FILE *opener( char *name )
{
    FILE *temp = fopen( name, "r" );
    if ( !temp )
    {
        perror( "fopen" );
        return( NULL );
    }
    return( temp );
}

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fin = opener( "/proc/stat" );

    if ( !fin )
        printf( "failed\n" );
    else
        printf( "fin=%p\n", fin );
}
```